# Not Found Cakephp Inner Page on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu

My friend configured Cakephp on his Windows PC then I copied that on my Ubuntu PC in /var/www/html/
then sat permissions `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/myproject`
when I run the project in browser by localhost/myproject it works but when I go to inner pages browser localhost/myproject/user/login shows not found on server...

please help me what shall I do?

Comment: There are a lot of things that can go wrong, so you will need the exact error to help us understand how the application is configured. Errors are normally written in `tmp/logs/error.log` which you will find under the project directory. Delete that file, try what fails and edit your question to add the results from `error.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your application not working, because you miss many steps to install CakePHP successful.** At the present, I also install CakePHP many times. Let's do this step by step:
with your context, put CakePHP in directory `/var/www/html/myproject`

**Step 1. Create virtual host**

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

at these line to end of line

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject
ServerName myproject.dev
<Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

# If you want more than one virtualhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject2
ServerName myproject2.dev
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/myproject2>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 2. Edit hosts file**

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
add these to end of file:
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
127.0.0.1 myproject2.dev
```

**Step 3. Enable mod_rewrite**

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**Step 4. Create .htaccess file in root folder**

```
cd /var/www/html/myproject
ls -la
sudo touch '.htaccess'
sudo gedit '.htaccess'
```

with content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 5. Enable read/write specific folder**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myproject/app/tmp
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myproject/app/tmp/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myproject/app/tmp/cache/persistent
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myproject/app/tmp/cache/models
```

**Step 6. Restart apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Step 7. Try in your browser**

```
http://myproject.dev
```

Comment: You find in directory **`/var/www/html/myproject/Config/`** , rename **`database.php.default`** to **`database.php`** . You will set constants for database connection in this file.